# Long text + lists in a single tabular cell

Tags: tables, itemize, text

I have been writing on a project on LaTeX that involves writing tables with a lot of text and some lists in it. Please look at the exemple below (Sorry for the poor quality) : [image]

Here is the LaTeX program that I wrote so far. It works well except for the last line where I can't fit all of the text I need to write.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm , right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
WP Title : & \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Project Administration}}\\  
\hline
Contractor : & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{NKCA Corp.} & WP No : & XXX\\
\hline
Start Event/Date : & T0 & & Issue Date : & XXX\\
\hline
End Event/Date : & Delivery & & Sheets & 1 of 1\\
\hline
WP Manager : & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{(Name)} & &\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\textbf{Items required to start WP : }}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance,
Arnaud.

Comment: It can be done. However, there will be a problem: such long cells cannot be broken across pages.

Comment: Thank you, it is not a problem because the text will be shorter than in the exemple.

Comment: you can try `\multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{\textbf{Items required to start WP : }
bla bla ....}`

Comment: actually, it works but the space between each item is too big... How can I change that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, using the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering\sffamily\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{l|}}
    \hline
    WP Title : & \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\textbf{Project Administration}}\\
    \hline
    Contractor : & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{NKCA Corp.} & WP No : & XXX\\
    \hline
    Start Event/Date : & T0 & & Issue Date : & XXX \\
    \hline
    End Event/Date : & Delivery & & Sheets & 1 of 1 \\
    \hline
    WP Manager : & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{(Name)} & &\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|p{12cm}|}{\setlist[itemize]{wide = 0pt, leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep = 3pt, before = \leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr \topsep\relax}}%
    \begin{description}[leftmargin = 0pt, topsep=8pt, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]%
    \item[Items required to start WP]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item KO meeting minutes
    \item Contractual documentation
    \end{itemize}
    \item[Tasks performed in WP]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Plan and manage the resources necessary to accomplish the project work and meet the objectives. Monitor the work progress.
    \item Maintain the set of resume of key personnel, and Project Directory.
    \item Ensure the establishment of the Project Management Information System.
    \item Ensure the establishment of the Risk management process and monitor maintenance of risk portfoilio.
    \end{itemize}
    \item[Tasks performed in WP]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Updated Project Organisation Breakdown Structure
    \item Progress reports \& Schedule update.
    \item Risk register.
    \item Minutes of meeting.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{description}
    }\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]